# Storing an ES6 Javascript class's getter/setter when inheritance is involed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

**Edit**: The reason I am doing the below process is so I can store the reference to the getter/setter in a dictionary. This allows me to have the key of my dictionary be an ID of an HTML element. Thus, if a property is changed in the HTML, I can do something like:

```
var propData = allMyGetterSetters[e.originalTarget.id];
propData.getSet.set(propData.obj, e.originalTarget.value);
```

This also allows me to do a loop and update all the HTML, should my logic change it.

---

I need to store a reference to the getter/setters of a few properties of one of classes. I've managed to do this with the following code:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(myClassObj.position), "x");
```

For simplicity, since I have to do this several times, I have the following method:

```
_makeGetSetObj(object, property){
    return {
        getSet: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(object), property),
        obj: object
    };
}
```

And subsequent code would look something like this:

```
var xPos = this._makeGetSetObj(myClassObj.position, "x");
// ...
xPos.getSet.get(xPos.obj);
```

All of this works perfectly.

However, I now need to store a reference to a getter/setter of my `myclassObj` object. However, the following does not work

```
this._makeGetSetObj(myClassObj, "name");
```

This actually gives me an error that `name` does not exist on the object. I've managed to figure out that the problem is my inheritance, which looks something like this

```
|-- BaseClass
  |-- MyClass
    |-- DerivedClass
```

The problem seems to be that `myClassObj` is actually an object of type `DerivedClass`, which doesn't have the property `name` on it.

So, if I do this:

```
this._makeGetSetObj(myClassObj.__proto__, "name");
```

It works to get the prototype, but when I try to use it as shown above (with my `xPos` example), it fails because it seems to still be storing an reference in `obj` as a `DerivedClass` object.

If I pull outside of my method, and try things manually, this works:

```
var name = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(myClassObj.__proto__), "name");
name.get(myClassObj);
```

This obviously breaks my method though, as one part requires the `__proto__` while the other part does not.

So, my question is: Is there a way to keep my current logic, or will I have to create a special method for the places with the described problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "store a handle to the getter/setters" mean?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00 Just what I show in the code snippets. Perhaps "reference" would have been a better word?

Comment: It seems it works. Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pcrfuuc9/

Comment: The purpose of calling accessors directly isn't clear, can you explain your case further? Accessors are there exactly to make this process transparent.

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak, read the full question. There's inheritance involved which is messing it up.

Comment: @estus, I'm translating object properties into HTML. In order to do this easily (i.e. in a loop) I need to have a dictionary with the ID's of the HTML elements, and a reference to the getter/setter. (Because those HTML elements can also be used to send a new value back.)

Comment: David, I think our problem here is that you don't clearly state in words near the beginning of the question what problem you're trying to solve.  Instead, you make us try to follow a long question and a whole bunch of logic and then try to guess what the real problem is here.  When you keep answering other people's comments with "read the question", that should be a clue that the question is not very clear.  People are reading it but don't understand the actual problem.  Right now this feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This doesn't explain why you need to go low level and call accessors directly. If you need to create a pair of getter/setter and use it later, it is as simple as `{ get: () => o[prop], set: (val) => { o[prop] = val } }`.

Comment: Ok. I got your issue. and fixed. here the final version: https://jsfiddle.net/pcrfuuc9/1/

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak, Added a line. Doesn't seem to be successful, since I don't get any alerts https://jsfiddle.net/pcrfuuc9/2/

Comment: @jfriend00, not an XY. See edit please.

Comment: @David Actually you should not the get alerts since it asserts if given argument is false. So if you dont get alerts that mean it all succeeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoded prototype doesn't smell good. Prototype chains should always be iterated:

```
let proto = obj;
let descriptor;
do {
  descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, prop);
} while (!descriptor && proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto))
...
```

This functionality has been already implemented by `Reflect`. Instead of parsing descriptors manually, it may be

```
const getSet = {
  get: () => Reflect.get(obj, prop),
  set: (val) => { Reflect.set(obj, prop, val) }
};
```

Or... just

```
const getSet = {
  get: () => obj[prop],
  set: (val) => { obj[prop] = val }
};
```

Because this is what happens when accessors are called directly.

Comment: Wow, that is so much cleaner than what I was doing! Now I'm a bit annoyed that I didn't find anything about using `Reflect` when I was researching how to do this. As a side note, the reason I am not iterating is because I don't want all the properties. Some are meant to only be used in code.

Comment: Yes, we've got it in ES6. It isn't obvious why is there the need to use a 'dictionary' like that, but it should be noticed that storing references to arbitrary things from DOM is a direct way to memory leaks.

Comment: The reason for a dictionary is so I can have an event on an input field, which will let me know when a value changes, and that new value can then be looked up and modified. Which, aside from cleaner code, this also allows me to modify what is hooked into the system by modifying only two places (1. Add the HTML box, 2. Add the line that allows JS to look it up and get/set the value).

Comment: On the memory leak, that is really good to know. Does this method have that risk? And if so, how can I clean up after myself, as the dictionary object can potentially be created/deleted a lot.

Comment: Sure, it looks like a risky pattern, usually I would suggest to stay away from such tricks, unless you know what you're doing really well. For more safety regarding leaks `WeakMap` may be used to store references.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but the trick is not because I have a few elements. This is what I have *so far* ([gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidA94/5b28f66949364fb61e608b6f461bba49)). I will take a look into WeakMap.